# Program that archives and manages not needed files

Tags: file-management, archiving

What I am looking for is a program that can archive old, "not needed anymore", "don't know where to put it" files. Something like the trash folder (well not exactly) but not for deletion, instead for archiving.
Perfectly, each file or folder would have a ID (to handle files and folders with same names).
I do not know if such program exists since I searched and find nothing like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LogicalDOC for this, it is a complete document management platform, and can do the most simple to the most complicated tasks, however I think you wish for a more simple solution. I would then ask you: are these file with important/classified content which you would be concerned?

If the answer is yes, then I would again suggest LogicalDOC. If the answer is no, I have other options for you:

- Use a specific cloud provider only for archiving. Most cloud offers a small free option for you to use as you wish, which for archiving files is excellent. I would suggest you pick a provider and create an account specifically for archiving these old documents. For a lot of space I suggest MEGA (50GB for free account). If you don't have that much files you can always look into other providers with less space.
- Alternative cloud provider: Evernote/OneNote. You can keep files (has a limitation on sizes though) organised and maintain in a database for later review. Also lets you search which is fantastic.

Hope this helps.

Links:

https://www.logicaldoc.com/download-logicaldoc-community

https://mega.co.nz/

https://evernote.com/